# How can I use sandbox in a class in c#

Tags: c#, class, oop, design-patterns, interface

I have homework about wpf samples and apply desing patterns on them. And I have a problem, using sandbox in a class. For example,

```
public void Colorize()
        {
            var uic = Sandbox.Children;
            foreach (Shape uie in uic)
            {
                uie.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
```

And I can not fix that mistake,

```
var uic = Sandbox.Children; // there is a problem here about "Sandbox"
```

Normally it works in this button,

```
private void MakeEverythingRed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uic = Sandbox.Children;
        foreach (Shape uie in uic)
        {
            uie.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```

And I have to apply these codes into class for strategy pattern. So, How can I solve this problem ? In summerly , How can Sandbox does not give me an error when it's compile. Thank you so much..

By the way I take them into a class,

```
class makeRed : makeSomething
    {
       public void Colorize()
        {
            var uic = Sandbox.Children;
            foreach (Shape uie in uic)
            {
                uie.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `Sandbox`? What error do you get?

Comment: Actually, I can access this Sandbox. Idk but it probably named dockpanel or stackpanel. Here: https://www.hizliresim.com/q5zttgh

Comment: OK, `Sandbox` is a `DockPanel`. What error do you get? You said "there is a problem here about Sandbox". What is the problem?

Comment: var uic = Sandbox.Children;
            foreach (Shape uie in uic)
            {
                uie.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }                                                                                                                                   I want to use this code in a class. But I can not access sandbox or this dockpanel. I want to access this sandbox in a class. For example, I want to create a method and make everything in that method in a class. For instance :

Comment: `class makeRed : makeSomething
    {
       public void Colorize()
        {
            var uic = Sandbox.Children;
            foreach (Shape uie in uic)
            {
                uie.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
    }` I used it. And CS0120 is error code.    Required for non-static field, method or property 'MainWindow.Sandbox'

Comment: Please edit your question with clarifications. It is difficult to follow if the changes are in comments.

Comment: I edited my problem